# Why Emulator (Android 8.0) not started from Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.3

Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 4.1, Windwows 10 (64 bit), RAM 8 GB, Processor: Intel(R), Core(TM) 3.3 GHz.

I create Emalator (Android 8.0). Default configuration. I nothing changed.

Here screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Now I started emulator from Android Studio:
[image]

Result:

In **Gradle console** in Android Studio:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.852 secs
```

In **Run console** in Android Studio:

```
08/23 12:14:40: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r myProject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk myproject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk myproject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.myproject/com.myproject.activity.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 3013 on device Nexus_8_0_API_26_size_3_7 [emulator-5554]
```

But application not start on emulator.
Here screenshot on emulator:
[image]

I close emulator. And run again. But resutl is the same. Emulator not started.

Why emulator not start? And as result Android application not started.

P.S. If I run my application on another emulator (e.g. Android 4.0) it's success run .
Here sreeeshot:
Select:

[image]

Success start:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are only able to install Oreo in nexus 5x or 6p emulator. That too with Ram size 4GB minimum for emulator.